# Spring AOP Dependency in GAE project

Tags: eclipse, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I have a Google App Engine project that I am building using Spring. I am running into a build problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor
```

All of my Spring jars are 4.1.6, and I've verified in Eclipse that those jars are on the build path. Any ideas what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Spring jars do you have in your build path? Depending on what .jars you have, it may not include Spring's external dependencies.

Try adding the aopalliance-1.0.jar, you can get it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0).

Comment: i had the spring-aop-4.1.6-release jar, but adding the aopalliance jar you suggested fixed it, thanks!